# Could recursive classes cause any problems

Tags: php, oop

Recently, while trying out different methods of dependency injection I stumbled across a concept where I may have classes that reference each other.

This could be pretty useful, I guess while trying to access a database object from a view, model or controller object for example.

But I just wandered if there would be any pitfalls?

Like memory leaks and so forth.

Sorry if it seems a stupid question but this idea is new, to me anyway.

```
class foo{

    public $bar;

}

class bar{

    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo=$foo;
        $this->foo->bar=$this;
    }
}

$foo = new foo;
$bar = new bar($foo);

var_dump($foo->bar->foo->bar->foo->bar->foo);

// object(foo)#1 (1) {
//   ["bar"]=>
//   object(bar)#5 (1) {
//     ["foo"]=>
//      *RECURSION*
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a code smell in any language. Circular dependency should be avoided at all costs. The solution is usually to abstract shared dependencies into a common class that does not depend on anything itself.

Comment: I would agree. I can't see any scenario within which this might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The example you give is somewhat artificial but, generally speaking it is perfectly valid to have classes instances that reference each other.

For instance, if you develop a parser, there are many situations like this, when you build the parse tree.

To elaborate a little bit, consider the class below extracted from Nikic excellent PHP parser written in PHP:
https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

You will see that an instance of `PHPParser_Node_Expr_Array`, that can obviously appear in a `PHPParser_Node_Expr` references itself in the `array` field other `PHPParser_Node_Expr` instances.

```
<?php

/**
 * @property PHPParser_Node_Expr_ArrayItem[] $items Items
 */
class PHPParser_Node_Expr_Array extends PHPParser_Node_Expr
{
    /**
     * Constructs an array node.
     *
     * @param PHPParser_Node_Expr_ArrayItem[] $items      Items of the array
     * @param int                             $line       Line
     * @param null|string                     $docComment Nearest doc comment
     */
    public function __construct(array $items = array(), $line = -1, $docComment = null) {
        parent::__construct(
            array(
                'items' => $items
            ),
            $line, $docComment
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP garbage collector before PHP 5.3 wasn't able to resolve circular references and  as a result wasn't able to release allocated memory for these objects and the whole connected graph of objects.

Now the issue is resolved: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

And sure always try to avoid overcomplicating your code.